# json_encode returns uncertain result, an array or an object

Tags: php, json

I find a weird result of `json_encode` today in my production code, sometimes it returns an array, like `["perl","php","python"]`, but sometimes an object, like `{"0":"perl","2":"python"}`. Here is a minimal example:

```
$a = array("perl", "php", "python", "something other");
foreach($a as $index => $item) 
{
    if ($item == "something")
        unset($a[$index]);
}
echo json_encode($a);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Why are you answering to yourself?

Comment: It's a Q&A-style, hope others can benefit from my experience. see [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know this thing...sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `foreach` loop, once `$item == "something"` is true, the array keys are not consecutively numerically indexed (except last iteration), then `json_encode` returns an object. If all the values in the array are not equal to "something", it returns an array. Since array is always what I want, I use `array_values()` before `json_encode`.

Comment: Why are you answering to yourself?